# Find multiple consecutive empty lines

Tags: r

I'm trying to chop up a text file into the articles it contains. Usually this is done by identifying a pattern each article begins with. Unfortunately the database I downloaded the articles from doesn't have that. The only pattern I can find is that after each article there are 3 empty lines.

How could I identify three consecutive empty line?
I know that I can find empty lines with:

```
Beginnings <- grep('^$', Lines.i)
```

Beginnings then looks like

```
> Beginnings[1:50]
[1]   1   2   3   6   8  10  12  13  40  41  42  43  45  49  50  51  53  54  62  63  64  65  67
[24]  69  70 110 111 112 113 115 117 121 122 123 125 131 132 133 135 137 138 150 151 152 153 155
[47] 157 158 169 170
```

You can see that the first article starts after `1 2 3` and the next one after `41 42 43`.

So my idea was to just add the newline expression to the pattern

```
Beginnings <- grep('^$\n^$\n^$\n', Lines.i)
```

But this does not work. I would be grateful for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution for extracting the article lines only. Turned out much more complex and cryptic than I'd been hoping, but I'm pretty sure it works. Also, thanks to akrun for the test data.

```
v1 <- c('ard','b','','','','rr','','fr','','','','','gh','d');
ind <- with(rle(c(rep(F,3),nzchar(v1),rep(F,3))),data.frame(start=cumsum(lengths[-length(lengths)])[values[-1]&!values[-length(values)]&lengths[-length(values)]>=3]-2,end=cumsum(lengths[-length(lengths)])[values[-length(lengths)]&!values[-1]&lengths[-1]>=3]-3));
articles <- lapply(1:nrow(ind),function(r) v1[ind[r,'start']:ind[r,'end']]);
v1;
##  [1] "ard" "b"   ""    ""    ""    "rr"  ""    "fr"  ""    ""    ""    ""    "gh"  "d"
ind;
##   start end
## 1     1   2
## 2     6   8
## 3    13  14
articles;
## [[1]]
## [1] "ard" "b"
##
## [[2]]
## [1] "rr" ""   "fr"
##
## [[3]]
## [1] "gh" "d"
```

Comment: Thanks! This was super useful! Also thanks a lot akrun. Your line of code actually already did what I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

You may try `rle`

```
which(inverse.rle(within.list(rle(!nzchar(v1)),
                 values[lengths<3 & values] <- FALSE)))
#[1]  3  4  5  9 10 11 12
```

#### data

```
 v1 <- c('ard', 'b', '', '', '', 'rr', '', 'fr', '', '', '', '', 'gh', 'd')
```

Comment: It's interesting that you needed to call `within.list()` explicitly, rather than relying on the S3 generic `within()`. This made me realize that the implicit class (`'list'` in this case) is not preserved when an explicit class (`'rle'` in this case) is assigned. Seems like a flaw in the R language to me. Any thoughts?

Comment: Good answer, though, +1.

Comment: @bgoldst Thanks, I don't know the exact reason why `within` wouldn't work here.